# Example 2.23 in Hatcher's algebraic topology: basis of homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image: Example 2.23: click]

Of course, I understand the first isomorphism and second isomorphism in this example. The problem is how induction can be used. I cannot really understand the red line. I have no idea so please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlined part of the proof shows that the (homology classes of the ) cycles $i_n$, $\partial i_n$ and $i_{n-1}$ (or anyway $-i_{n-1}$) do correspond between themselves through the given isomorphisms.

Now by inductive hypothesis $i_{n-1}$ is a generator of $H_{n-1}(\Delta^{n-1},\partial \Delta^{n-1})$, so $\partial i_n$ is a generator of $H_n(\partial\Delta^n,\Lambda)$ and hence $i_n$ is a generator of $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$, (because they are images of each other through the isomorphisms).

The induction proves that indeed each $i_n$ is a generator for $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got whay you said, thanks. But I tried over and over but failed to complete my calculation that shows why $i_{n-1}$ becomes $i_n$ through two isomorphisms. That is I want to know the detail course. Can you help me?

Comment: @Herace The first isomorphism sends $i_n$ in $\partial i_n$, the second sends $i_{n-1}$ in either $\partial i_n$ or $-\partial i_n$ so the composite of the first isomorphism with the inverse of the second isomorphism gives an isomorphism that sends $i_n$ in $i_{n-1}$.... does this answer to your question?

Comment: Actually I want to know the detail course how $i_n$ becomes $\partial i_n$ or how $\partial i_n$ becomes $i_{n-1}$. I have tried this in chain-level but failed. Thanks to read.

Comment: I solved finally, need no helps.

Comment: Sorry for not answering ... I had no time, but I'm glad you'd completed the computations :)